# How to determine if Appointment Object was sent?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to get a "Sent" property for an `AppointmentItem` to determine if the invitation was sent or not - either cancelled by user after clicking the displayed window or server issues.

While I read that the appointment has a [Saved Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_properties.aspx), this doesn't tell me if it was sent like the one in [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx).

I don't think the code would be helpful, but, here it is:

```vb
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAgenda As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olAgenda = olApp.CreateItem(1)

With olAgenda
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Recipients.Add = "sample@domain.com"
    .Display
    On Error Resume Next

    'here is where I would need to catch the kind of "was it sent?" variable.
    Call .ItemProperties.Item("Saved")
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then             '99. If Error
        MsgBox "Item Send"
    Else                               '99. If Error
        MsgBox "Item Not Send"
    End If                             '99. If Error
    
End With
```

Please note, I don't like late binding, reference for Outlook library has to be added.

How could I catch if the `AppointmentItem` was sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appointment itself is never sent - its stays in the Calendar folder. Only `MeetingItem` objects are sent.

That being said, use the [AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869205.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I have to add that when you are using it as condition, 0 means it is "not available" -for my problem, outlook couldn't "send it"- and 1 it is available.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869427.aspx for the possible values of the olMeetingStatus enum.